# Plotar a média no R

Tags: r

como eu posso plotar a média usando o R Studio e conseguir exibir a mesma com meu conjunto de dados também apresentados no espaço dimensional? A média é representada por essa reta e os dados representados por pontinhos.
O código que to usando é apenas para cálculo da média.. queria que ela aparecesse na ilustração

```
dados <- dbGetQuery(con, "select departure_hour, travel_segment_time from bartolomeumitre; dados.frame <- data.frame(dados); plot(dados.frame); xl <- with(dados.frame, travel_segment_time); mean(xl)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode postar o código que você está usando para plotar os dados no espaço dimensional?

Comment: O que é plotar a média?

Comment: Oi Daniel, eu gostaria que o valor da média aparecesse no espaço (x,y) junto com os dados. Vou tentar inserir uma imagem na pergunta inicial para ser mais clara.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com o `ggplot2`, você pode fazer assim:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data_frame(x = rnorm(100), y = x + rnorm(100))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x,  y = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(y))) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(x)))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No seu caso, assim deve funcionar:

```
ggplot(dados.frame, aes(y = travel_segment_time, x = departure_hour)) +          
  geom_point() + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(travel_segment_time)))
```

Comment: Editei a resposta, veja se funciona

Comment: Consegui, Daniel! Assim, ggplot(dados.frame, aes(x=departure_hour, y=travel_segment_time)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(travel_segment_time))) 

Obrigada!